# Generating ordinal characters in JSP EL

Tags: java, jsp

Take the following JSP fragment:

```
<c:forEach items="${items}" varStatus="status">
   ${'A' + status.index}
</c:forEach>
```

The intent should clear, I'm trying to generate an 'A'-based character index for each iterations through the loop. In Java, this is fine (e.g. `'A' + 1 == 'B'`), but JSP EL on Tomcat 6 barfs with `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "A"`. It seems it cannot handle characters as ordinal values.

The current solution breaks this out into a custom taglib, but this is absurd for something so trivial.

Can anyone see how to persuade EL to do this calculation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create the alphabet:

```
<c:set var="alphabet" value="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"/>
```

Then you can use fn:substring to access letters.

```
${fn:substring(alphabet, status.index, status.index + 1)}
```

Your example would become:

```
<c:forEach items="${items}" varStatus="status">
    <c:set var="indexOfLetter" value="${fn:indexOf('A', alphabet) + status.index}"/>
    ${fn:substring(alphabet, indexOfLetter, indexOfLetter + status.index + 1}
</c:forEach>
```

You'll probably need some edge case checking, but this should work.

Comment: I'm going to pick this one, since it's the most general-purpose of the 3 answers so far, allowing me to set a JSP variable with the result. The other two rely on HTML or CSS to render to render the ordinal into a character, which is appealing in many situations, but not what I need for my current problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
<c:forEach items="${items}" varStatus="status">
  &#${65 + status.index};
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Very crafty! 2 characters of well-localised cleverness.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible with pure EL. It basically only understands strings, numbers and javabeans. If it didn't have thrown a `NumberFormatException`, you would still end up with `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, etc. Semantically seen, your best bet is likely using HTML `<ol>` element with a little shot of CSS to make it a fullworthy alphabetical-indexed list:

```
<ol style="list-style-type: upper-alpha;">
    <c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
        <li>${item}</li>
    </c:forEach>
</ol>
```

This will generate

```
A. item1
B. item2
C. item3
...
```

If that's also not what you want, consider an EL function which returns the desired char for the given index. Or have a look at Pointy's clever solution which basically generates XML entities on the fly.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the result value as a JSP variable, so I can pass it to other tags. Thanks for the lateral thinking, though :)